# What does アレがある mean in this context ? [Manga]

Tags: manga, japanese-to-english, conversations

Context : MC invited a hungry girl (A-chan) to join in and eat Ramen with him in a Ramen shop. The shop owner suggests that if the girl orders too much things to put in a ramen bowl, it can't hold that many portions.

> Shop Owner: でもそれだけご所望だと、この椀じゃあとても入りきりませんぜ？
>
> A-chan: 大丈夫なのだ。**アレがある**のだ。
>
> MC's thought: と、A-chanが指を差すのは、大人が腕を回してもとても届かないだろう、超巨大なラーメン鉢。

Can someone explain to me what she means exactly with **アレがある** ?

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799) here on the Japanese Stack Exchange.  We are happy to help out with specific points of grammar and understanding.  So what is your best guess as to what アレがある means?

Comment: The answer is right there in the context with the exact words.

Comment: @4chanuser, Your questions almost always get close votes because you refuses to show any prior research effort about the expression in question. This time I decided to answer because アレ is so basic a word, but please take the above comment seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This アレ ("that") refers to 超巨大なラーメン鉢. Do you understand she is saying あれ while pointing her finger to the ramen bowl? This is the simplest  usage of あれ or "that".